# How to hide an iframe after clicking with JQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, iframe

im trying to setup a simple panel that follows the mouse movements with an external iframe. And i want to hide it after its clicked. What i've got so far:

```
<div id="wrapper45" onclick="hideitnow(this)" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity = 50); margin-left: -50px; z-index: 100;"> 
    <script src="thescriptthatcallstheframe"></script>
</div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
        $( "#link" ).mousemove( function( e ) {
            $( '#wrapper45' ).css( {
                top: e.pageY - 50,
                left: e.pageX + 25
            } );
        } );
    } )
</script>
```

the hideitnow function:

`<script type="text/javascript"> 
function hideitnow(elem){ 
document.getElementById(elem).style.display = 'none';
} 
</script>`

does anyone have a clue why its not working!?
thx in advance!

Comment: why dont you use jquery(elem).hide() function?

Comment: So you are trying to detect a click on a iFrame that has a page loaded from a different domain?

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $("#link").mousemove(function(e) {
            $('#wrapper45').css({
                top: e.pageY - 50,
                left: e.pageX + 25
            });
        });
        $('#wrapper45').live('click', function() {
            $(this).css({display: 'none'});
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: thanks, just tried your suggestion and it didnt work! could you integrate in the snippet i provided so i know im doing it right?

Comment: Copy and paste that exactly (edited version). Also i take it #wrapper45 isn't inserted via ajax? Else you will need a live click function (which is simple enough).

Comment: @Joao - Also remember to remove the inline onclick from the div.

Comment: ok, i tried that and it didnt work. i think the problem is that the iframe is external so the click is going to the inner element and the javascript is outside, not in the same document!! any way around this!?

Comment: isnt there any relation between the main page and the iframe!? i mean, is the main window parent and the iframe child!?

Comment: @Joao - Just incase (I got a feeling that wrapper isn't hardcoded) Copy and paste the newly edited version. If not, get a live version up and I'll take a look.

Comment: `<div id="wrapper45" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0.5; filter: alpha(opacity = 50); margin-left: -50px; z-index: 100;"> 
  <script src="http://othersite.com/something.php?s=x"></script>
 </div> 
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(function() {
        $("#link").mousemove(function(e) {
            $('#wrapper45').css({
                top: e.pageY - 50,
                left: e.pageX + 25
            });
        });
        $('#wrapper45').click(function() {
            $(this).css({display: 'none'});
        });
    });
</script>`

Comment: @tfbox - i dont have control over the contents of the iframe im showing!! thought you might know that, i guess! :s

Comment: @tfbox - the wrapper45 on the stylesheet:

div.wrapper45 { width: 100%; height: 100%; overflow: auto; }

Comment: @Joao - I've tried everything in jsfiddle can't seem to find a solution. Your best bet is to search google for "jQuery iframe click function"

Comment: @Joao - No problem, if you find/come up with a solution please let me know here.